# Boat and Arc Length problem

Tags: maxima-minima

Boat men wants to reach at exact opposite point of river,which is 40m wide. Speed of boat in still water is 5m/sec and that of river is 2 m/sec . Find following 
1- Angle at which he needs to start journey from starting point.
2-length of arc (shortest possible) , which boat would travel.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HInGO.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would it be possible to have a completely straight trajectory? Try vector addition.

Answer (score 0):

### Hint 1

To reach the exact opposite point, component of velocity along the river should be zero.

Hence, the angle with the river bank is such that $5 \cos{\theta} = 2$.

> $$\theta = \arccos{\frac{2}{5}} \approx 66.4 \deg$$

### Hint 2

Length of shortest arc length will be $40 m$ since path of boat is a straight line.

**Related Problem for you to try**

> Solve the problem if speed of boat is $2 \frac{m}{s}$ and speed of water is $5 \frac{m}{s}$. That is, the speeds are interchanged.